# Prevent form from resubmitting after button click

Tags: python, django, forms

I have a Django project where I have a few forms. What is happening is when I click button submit 30 times, my data is inserted 30 times in the database. I did my research and I saw lots of jquery or javascript solutions in general but I am not familiar much with them so I am trying to find a more pythonic/django solution.
The frontend solution that works for me was:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var form = document.getElementById('post_form');
    var submitButton = document.getElementById('submit');
    form.addEventListener('submit', function () {
        submitButton.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
        submitButton.value = 'Please wait...';
    }, false);
</script>
```

Here is my code now and I was hoping to find some way to make it work without the above:

views:

```
@method_decorator(login_required(login_url='index', redirect_field_name=None), name='dispatch')
class CreatePostView(views.FormView):
    model = Post
    form_class = CreatePostForm
    template_name = 'posts/create_post.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        post = form.save(commit=False)
        post.user = self.request.user
        post.save()
        return redirect('index')
```

template:

```
<form action="{% url 'create post' %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ form.as_p }}
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Submit</button>
    </p>
</form>
```

model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    MAX_TITLE_LENGTH = 20
    MIN_TITLE_LENGTH = 3
    MAX_DESTINATION_LENGTH = 30
    MIN_DESTINATION_LENGTH = 3
    MAX_DESCRIPTION_LENGTH = 550
    MIN_DESCRIPTION_LENGTH = 5

    title = models.CharField(
        max_length=MAX_TITLE_LENGTH,
        validators=(MinLengthValidator(MIN_TITLE_LENGTH), name_and_title_validator),
        error_messages={
            'max_length': f'Post title must be a maximum of {MAX_TITLE_LENGTH} characters.',
            'min_length': f'Post title must be at least {MIN_TITLE_LENGTH} characters long.',
        },
        null=False,
        blank=False,
    )

    photo = CloudinaryField(
        folder='mediafiles/post_photos',
        public_id=get_photo_name_by_post_name,
        null=False,
        blank=False,
    )

    destination = models.CharField(
        max_length=MAX_DESTINATION_LENGTH,
        validators=(MinLengthValidator(MIN_DESTINATION_LENGTH), ),
        error_messages={
            'max_length': f'Destination must be a maximum of {MAX_DESTINATION_LENGTH} characters.',
            'min_length': f'Destination must be at least {MIN_DESTINATION_LENGTH} characters long.',
        },
        null=False,
        blank=False,
    )

    description = models.CharField(
        max_length=MAX_DESCRIPTION_LENGTH,
        validators=(MinLengthValidator(MIN_DESCRIPTION_LENGTH), ),
        error_messages={
            'max_length': f'Description must be a maximum of {MAX_DESCRIPTION_LENGTH} characters.',
            'min_length': f'Description must be at least {MIN_DESCRIPTION_LENGTH} characters long.',
        },
        null=False,
        blank=False,
    )

    category = models.ForeignKey(
        PostCategory,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        default='',
        null=False,
        blank=False,
    )

    user = models.ForeignKey(
        UserModel,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=False,
        blank=True,
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

form:

```
class CreatePostForm(AddPlaceholdersFormMixin, RemoveLabelsFormMixin, AddStyleClassFormMixin, forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        exclude = ('user', )
        labels = {
            'category': 'CHOOSE A CONTINENT',
        }

        widgets = {
            'description': forms.Textarea(),
        }
```

I tried redirecting after form.save() and it is successful but it doesn't solve my issue about resubmit. I had another problem with resubmission on refresh and I solved it with sessions but here I am not sure how to do it. I have to say again that I understand there is a frontend javascript solution but I want to know if it can be done on the server side rather than the client's.

Comment: If you redirect to a DetailView of the Post that has been created (with an Edit link to an UpdateView) then the user won't invoke the CreateView again. The problem is that he doesn't see any confirmation that the post has succeeded, so uses the browser back button and tries again. Preventing this  is a client-side issue, and is probably browser-specific. (This is why the default get_success_url is the get_absolute_url method of the created object, if it exists)

Comment: server-side you could check for the non-existence of a `Post` with an exact same set of fields. A creation time field might further help (i.e. its an error if the same or very similar was created in the last N minutes).